# How to customize Beamer "definition" environment?

Tags: beamer, cjk

I want to redefine the "definintion" block environment. From the original to this:
`\begin{定理} 定理内容（theorem details) \end{定理}.` After a lot of test I notice there are some difference among  Definitions, Theorems,Lemma block environment,and so on, such as itemization marker shape and color.I want replace definition with "定理“Any instructions will be appreciate,thanks advance.

Here in the code:

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt]{beamer} 
%\usecolortheme[named=Plum]{structure} 
%\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
%\setbeamerfont{title}



%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\usepackage{CJKspace}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{latexsym,bm,amsmath,amssymb}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\mode <presentation>

%\title[TINLPN]{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
%\author[赵]{赵moumou \\ \texttt{euclid@123.com}}
%\date[ISPN'80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}


%%
\title{专题Largest Prime Number}
\author[赵]{赵moumou \\ \texttt{euclid@tokoyo.edu}}
\institute[UMBC]{UMBCdjskfljadfl}
\date[2013-07-09]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
%%
%%第一个frame
\begin{frame}



\titlepage
\end{frame}


%第二个frame
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame名称}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}


%About Section and Subsection
%\section{Motivation}
%\subsection{The Basic Problem That We Studied}


%%第三个frame%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{What Are Prime Numbers?}      

   \begin{definition}{定理}
    A \alert{prime number} is a number that has exactly two divisors.
   \end{definition}
    \pause
  \begin{exampleblock} {例子}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 2 is prime (two divisors: 1 and 2).
      \pause
    \item 3 is prime (two divisors: 1 and 3).
      \pause
    \item 4 is not prime (\alert{three} divisors: 1, 2, and 4).
    \end{itemize}
   \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

%%第四个frame%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
例题：\\
\small{$f'(x)=3x+89$}
已知$g(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\ln x$\\好题份额常量定积分历代快速就阿德理科sjdefdf
\end{frame}

\end{CJK}
\end {document}
```

Here is a screenshot about the relative frame by which I want to show "定理（theorem）“.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These definitions come from the `amsthm` package which is loaded by `beamer`.

So you can define your own "definition" adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[theorem]{定理}
```

Now, instead of

```
\begin{definition}{定理}
 A \alert{prime number} is a number that has exactly two divisors.
\end{definition}
```

write

```
\begin{mydef}
 A \alert{prime number} is a number that has exactly two divisors.
\end{mydef}
```

and you will have:

[image]

You can change the `\theoremstyle` to `plain` or `example` to get different appearance.

Comment: And supposing you want to keep using the default block name (definition)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to define a new environment with command using Chinese characters "定理", or just want the environment title appear differently? For the latter, add

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dingli}{定理}
```

to the preamble, so that

```
\begin{dingli}
A \alert{prime number} is a number that has exactly two divisors.
\end{dingli}
```

will give you

[image]

If, however, you want to use command \begin{定理}\end{定理} instead. Then you will need to typeset with engine that provide full support for Unicode characters, such as XeTex. In that case you have to use package xeCJK instead of CJK.