# Beamer citation formating in definition

Tags: beamer, formatting, citing

I'm trying to insert a citation after a definition/theorem in the beamer class to resemble the following:

Definition [1]

Here is my definition.

I can partially accomplish the above using

```
\begin{definition}[\cite{ref_01}]
```

but this yields
Definition ([1]) with an additional set of brackets. Is there anyway of selectively removing the additional round brackets?

Comment: Whay not a plain `\begin{definition}\leavevmode\cite{ref_01}`?

Comment: The puts the citation in the body of the definition and and besides the word definition.

Comment: Can you please make up a minimal example?

Comment: Do you mean the `Definition xx` label is  on a separate line?

Comment: You probably need to customize `definition`'s definition. See:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124357/how-to-customize-beamer-definition-environment